# Eclipse Mars JBoss EAP 6.2 - Remote connection failed

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

When I try to start JBoss EAP 6.2 in Eclipse Mars the console output always end with:

```
2016-03-08 08:15:21,978 INFO  [as] [.|||] JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
2016-03-08 08:15:21,979 INFO  [as] [.|||] JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
2016-03-08 08:15:21,979 INFO  [as] [.|||] JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.2.4.GA (AS 7.3.4.Final-redhat-1) started in 6468ms - Started 471 of 614 services (118 services are passive or on-demand)
```

And then it's getting error periodically till it's terminated:

```
2016-03-08 08:08:48,810 ERROR [connection] [.|||] JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856
```

Nothing is being deployed (not from eclipse, either deployments folder is empty).

When I close Eclipse Mars and reopen the same workspace with Eclipse Kepler the JBoss EAP 6.2 strats fine.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should check if there is any process running which is sending a wrong signal/message to your port or to a Remoting related port. Try to open this ip in your browser or change the port in your standalone.xml of your JBoss.

Comment: tried to change ports but nothing happend, I'm not aware of any proccess running that tries to (probably wrongly address the service), I also tried to find the proccess in task manager and I found nothing. It's also weird that it's actually working in Eclipse Kepler

Comment: from tcp/ip monitor view in eclipse I acknowledge the request that is periodically send: GET / HTTP/1.1,
Sec-JbossRemoting-Key: AfeTV9rlnFZwhWLqcyOxlg==,
Upgrade: jboss-remoting,
Host: localhost:11475,
Connection: upgrade. Response is: Error: Could not connect to server.

Comment: What do you see if you place the ip and port in your browser i.e. http://localhost:8081?

Comment: I've got nothing defined to listen on 8081 is standalone.xml, JBoss Management is supposed to be on 9999 and JBoss Web on 8080, but non of them actually works (blank page - nothing).

Answer (score 0):

This morning I tried to start JBoss and everything works fine, I really don't know what happend because I hadn't done anything. Never mind, everything works fine. Thanx guys for trying to help.